# Display images from folder in table using php,html?

Tags: php, image, directory, tabular

I want to display my images in table form. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$files = glob("images/*.*");
for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
    $image = $files[$i];
    $supported_file = array(
        'gif',
        'jpg',
        'jpeg',
        'png'
    );

    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if (in_array($ext, $supported_file)) {
        echo basename($image);
echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="Random image" ,width=100px, height=100px /><br>';
} else {
continue;
}
}
?>
```

[image]

Something like that picture.

Comment: just create the table markup, `<table>` and `<tr>` and `<td>`

Comment: Using a `for`loop to iterate over the images is a valid approach, but you forgot to add the table structure to your output. Without that no table will get rendered by the browser. I suggest you read a few lines about how a table is defined in html markup. You define the table using the table elements (rows and cells), inside cells you then output the image like you already do.

Comment: What is your actual output? Maybe another mistake in your thinking is that PHP uses the file systems's file paths (absolute paths) whereas HTML uses paths relative to the document root. So you need to convert the PHP path to a path that HTML can work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it in table the simply add table tag with  and  to it

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Image Name</th>
  <th>Image</th>
</tr>
<?php
$files = glob("images/*.*");
for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
    $image = $files[$i];
    $supported_file = array(
        'gif',
        'jpg',
        'jpeg',
        'png'
    );

    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if (in_array($ext, $supported_file)) {
      echo "<tr><td>";
      echo basename($image);
      echo "</td><td>";
      echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="Random image" ,width=100px, height=100px /><br>';
      echo "</td></tr>";
} else {
continue;
}
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Help me a lot. :)

Answer (score 2):

Change your html code from:

`echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="Random image" ,width=100px, height=100px /><br>';`

to

```
  echo "<table border='1'>";
  echo "<tr><td>";
  echo basename($image);
  echo "</td><td>";
  echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="Random image" ,width=100px, height=100px />';
  echo "</td></tr>";
  echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Help me a lot. :)